# Shortest path algorithm is too slow

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, pathfinding

I am solving one problem with shortest path algorithm, but it is too slow.

The problem is that I have N points and these can be connected only if the distance between them is smaller or equal than the D.  I have a `start` index and finish(`ciel` in code) index and have to return the shortest path in double format.

Firstly I thought that the `sqrt` is too slow, but when I changed it, it was still too slow. I am backtracking the distance and using `sqrt` just there for better speed, but it is too slow. I have used a priority queue. For more information, the input consists of the X and Y of the points , D maximal distance to make edge, start index and finish index. There can be max 1000 points.

// The main problem is that, it crashes of memory, I do not think I use so much of it but, it crashes from bad_alloc

[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/pQS29Vw9).

Are there any ways of making it faster, please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 1001;
const int INF = 1e9;

std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > edges[MAX]; // hrany a vzdialenosti medzi bodmi a hranami
int N; // pocet vrcholov
int start, ciel; // start a ciel index

double dijkstra() {
    int vis[N]; // pocet navstiveni daneho bodu
    int prevNodes[N][2];
    for(int i=0;i < N;i++)
        prevNodes[i][1] = INF;

    std::priority_queue< std::pair<int, int> > heap; // halda
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) vis[i] = 0;
    heap.push(pair<int, int>(0, start));
    while(!heap.empty())
    {
        pair<int, int> min = heap.top(); // vybratie dalsieho
        heap.pop(); // vyhodenie pozreteho
        min.first *= -1.0; // kvoli spravnemu fungovaniu priority
        int v = min.second; // len pre oko

        vis[v]++;
        if (v == ciel && vis[v] == 1)
        {
            double d = 0.0; 

            int prevIndex = ciel, nextIndex = prevNodes[ciel][0]; 

            while(1)
            {

                for(int j=0;j < edges[nextIndex].size();j++)
                    if(edges[nextIndex][j].first == prevIndex)
                    {

                        d += sqrt(double( edges[nextIndex][j].second ));
                        break;
                    }

                prevIndex = nextIndex; // posunutie
                if(nextIndex == start) // ak sme uz na zaciatku
                    break;
                else
                    nextIndex = prevNodes[nextIndex][0];// posun dalej
            }
            return d; // najkratsia cesta
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) edges[v].size(); i++)
        {
            if (vis[edges[v][i].first] < 1)
            {
                if(prevNodes[edges[v][i].first][1] > min.first + edges[v][i].second)
                {
                    prevNodes[edges[v][i].first][0] = min.second;

                    prevNodes[edges[v][i].first][1] = min.first + edges[v][i].second;
                }
                heap.push(pair<int, int>(-(min.first + edges[v][i].second), edges[v][i].first)); 
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int X;
    scanf("%d",&X);
    double answers[X];
    for(int i=0;i < X;i++)
    {
        int D, sIndex, eIndex; // N je globalne
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &D); // N
        int DD = D * D;
        for(int j=0;j < N;j++)
            edges[j].clear();

        int V[N][2]; // N
        int x, y;
        for(int k=0;k < N;k++) // N
        {
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            V[k][0] = x;
            V[k][1] = y;
        }

        for(int a=0;a < N;a++)
            for(int b=0;b < N;b++)
            {

                int v = (((V[a][0] - V[b][0]) * (V[a][0] - V[b][0]) +
                                (V[a][1] - V[b][1]) * (V[a][1] - V[b][1])));
                if(v > DD)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    edges[a].push_back(pair<int, int>(b, v));
                    edges[b].push_back(pair<int, int>(a, v));
                }
            }

        scanf("%d %d", &start, &ciel);
        start--;
        ciel--;
        double dijLen = dijkstra();
        if(dijLen < 0)
            answers[i] = -1;
        else
            answers[i] = dijLen;
    }
    for(int i=0;i < X;i++)
        if(answers[i] < 0)
            printf("Plan B\n");
        else
            printf("%.2f\n", answers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple things that I see that would make this a lot more efficient:

First, you don't need to determine all of the valid edges before you start the Dijkstra algorithm.  Assuming that the only constraint on whether two points have a valid edge is that "the distance between them is smaller or equal than the D", there is no reason to determine the complete connection tree before entering the path search.  The loop in main is essentially just computing the distance from every node to every other node, with up to 1000 nodes.  This gives the maximum number of distance calculations as 1000 *factorial*. Since the weight for any given edge is only the distance between them, it would be much better to just assume that all nodes are connected and reject edges *inside* the Dijkstra algorithm if the edge distance is greater than D.

Second, you don't need to test all of the resulting edges within the Dijkstra algorithm. You can cut down on your set of edges to weigh by filtering them each time you take a step through the tree, and only calculate distances (and thus edge weighting) for nodes that are possible edges.  You only have to calculate distances between any two nodes where both x[a] - x[b] and y[a] - y[b] are less than D.  Taking this a step further, you only have to calculate square roots on the set of nodes where delta x plus delta y are equal *and* are the lowest value. This takes the vast majority of the math that is currently being performed with relatively expensive multiply and root calls and replaces it with cheap additions and subtractions.

Third, depending on the distribution of the input set and the method you chose for rejecting edges in the Dijkstra algorithm, it might be faster to sort the input set before you start.  That way you can just ignore any indices that fall outside of your distance constraint from the current node. Even if you are only sorting by one of the coordinates, it gives a really easy way to identify edges that have a distance greater than D because you don't have to traverse the entire set of nodes each time you are applying edge weights.

Comment: I implemented the first and the third, but the heap sometimes ran out of memory with 1000 points, crashes, I checked it and it has about 67 000 000 items at the crash.

Comment: Here is modified code, can you check it for logic errors due to wrong answer text please? http://pastebin.com/0WiuVCNM

Comment: I tried the A* way because it was crashing due to heap overflow. Here it is pastebin.com/sNf1w55c , I am waiting response from judge because it cannot get compiled on their compiler.

Comment: I fixed it, but now I am getting wrong answer again, can somebody check the code logic please?

Answer (score 11):

**C++-specific:**

- You're mixing C and C++ libraries:

  - You already have `<iostream>`, so you don't need `<stdio.h>`.

    However, if you can *only* use `printf` and `scanf` for whatever reason, then remove `<iostream>`.  Otherwise, just use `std::cout` and `std::cin`, and remove `<stdio.h>`.
  - The C++ library version of `<stdlib.h>` is `<cstdlib>`.
  - The C++ library version of `<math.h>` is `<cmath>`.
- Global variables is bad practice:

  ```
  std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > edges[MAX];
  int N;
  int start, ciel;
  ```

  Prefer to pass these variables to functions as needed, or keep them in the one needed function.  Having them global can introduce bugs, which will just make maintenance more difficult.
- Although you're not doing *everything* in `main()` (which is good), you still seem to be doing quite a bit in it.  If `dijkstra()` is supposed to handle most of the work, then you may need more functions to call from `main()`.  It should *not* be doing the hard work; that's for the other functions.

  From a maintainability standpoint, also, this isn't the best approach.  You should mostly be taking the initial input, give it to the function(s) to do the work, then receive and display the results.
- This loop:

  ```
  for(int i=0;i < X;i++)
      if(answers[i] < 0)
          printf("Plan B\n");
      else
          printf("%.2f\n", answers[i]);
  ```

  should have curly braces:

  ```
  for(int i=0;i < X;i++)
  {
      if(answers[i] < 0)
          printf("Plan B\n");
      else
          printf("%.2f\n", answers[i]);
  }
  ```

**Performance:**

- Part of your performance issue may have to do with the nested `for`-loops in `main()`.  At the least, you'll have O(n<sup>2</sup>), which will already be quite large, depending on the number.  You then have a loop outside of that, which will increase this complexity.

  Overall, you have many loops throughout the program, which, alongside the performance issue, *could* be an indication that your algorithm implementation in't ideal.  You also don't use `new` or `malloc` anywhere, so one of the container operations may be throwing `bad_alloc`.  You may need to use breakpoints to determine this, perhaps where you call `push()` and `push_back()`.

Comment: I know about all these things, but when I am tweaking and playing with it I use some of them sometimes.

Comment: @user36546: If so, that should be stated in the explanation for the reviewers.

Comment: I do not think it has something to do with the real problem or its part. It is unimportant.

Comment: @user36546: True, but on Code Review, feedback on anything is fair game.  Specific questions are still important, but they don't have to be the only things addressed.

Comment: Nested for loops in main are for for checking the distance between points and adding edge if there can exist.

Comment: It's not fair game when the nitpicky stuff has nothing to do with the performance crux of his question.

Comment: @0A0D - See the [help/on-topic] for what is fair-game... it clearly says: `6. Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?`

Comment: Ok, I give. It's still doesn't make sense.. what a waste of time /opinion

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking:

> `distance` < `D` // distance has `sqrt` calculations

try checking

> (`distance` squared) < (`D` squared)

No `sqrt` is required, equivalent to your test case (i.e. no imaginary distances, right?).